# configure nginx to get js and css directly from public folder of node.js express site

Tags: node.js, nginx, express

I got `node.js express` site on port `3000`. And it is configured to work with nginx.
It worked well through nginx until I decided to configure nginx to get css, js and image files directly from `public` folder without node.js express:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# cat myDomain.com.public 
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myDomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myDomain.com.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
    location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
          root /root/pathToNodeJsExpressSiteFolder/public; 
          access_log off;
          expires max;
        }

}
```

But now this site works without css and js. It returns `403 forbidden` requesting them:

```
style.css
/stylesheets
GET
403
Forbidden
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Just a comment, but add `modified` to `expires`, so it will look: `expires modified max`. So browser will check if resources are changed and will reload them in that case, otherwise you will face issues with caching and complexities over clearing the cache in browsers.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs I changed row `expires max;` to `expires modified max;` and it now it throws error on this line: `nginx: [emerg] "expires" directive invalid value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it requires both read and execute privilege to the directory and **all parent directories** of this directory for those static resources on file system for nginx. If you found some entries in your nginx error log like:

```
open() "/root/pathToNodeJsExpressSiteFolder/public/stylesheets/style.css" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Then you need:

```
$ sudo chmod +rx /root/pathToNodeJsExpressSiteFolder/public
$ sudo chmod +rx /root/pathToNodeJsExpressSiteFolder
$ sudo chmod +rx /root
```

**Note**: `$ sudo chmod +rx /root` is not recommended because it always limits non-root user to access `/root`.

Answer (score 0):

A `403 forbidden` response may be related to the nginx process don't having permission to read the files. Check that the folder `public` is recursively readable by the user running `nginx` and change the permissions if needed:

```
sudo chmod -R 744 /root/pathToNodeJsExpressSiteFolder/public
```

Comment: I have changed rights to public folder and checked them: `ls -ld /root/pathToNodeJsExpressSiteFolder/public
drwxr--r-- 5 root root 4096 Sep  6 09:45 /root/pathToNodeJsExpressSiteFolder/public`. Restarted nginx. But result is the same `403 forbidden`

Comment: @efr Hum... and the files inside are 744 too?

Comment: yep `/root/pathToNodeJsExpressSiteFolder/public/stylesheets# ls -ld style.css
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 2463 Sep  6 09:58 style.css`

Comment: Thank you, Pablo. Dont know what to do :)

Comment: @efr would you mind checking the nginx error log to see what causes the 403 response? and it sees that your files are owned by user `root`. what is the user that runs the `nginx` process?

Comment: @shawnzhu master nginx process run by root, worker processes run by `www-data` user. Yep  nginx error log got: `2013/09/14 05:33:29 [error] 17119#0: *11 open() "/root/pathToNodeJsExpressSiteFolder/public/stylesheets/style.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: ip, server: mydomain, request: "GET /stylesheets/style.css HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain", referrer: "http://mydomain/"`